# why is socket.id undefined in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

If i do console.log(socket) i get a socket object in firebug. In the obj I could see a property with `id` and i could see the value of the id. But when I do console.log(socket.id) i get undefined. why?

```
   var socket = io();
    $(document).ready( function(){
        console.log(socket);
        console.log(socket.id);
        console.log(socket.ids);
        $(".click").on("click", function(e){
            alert("clicked")
            socket.emit("clicked", socket.id)
            $(this).addClass("removeclick");
        })
     });
```

ps I could get `socket.ids` which is 0 but not socket.id.

Comment: When I do `console.log()` in firebug it works as expected. Have you tried that?

Comment: Also, try changing your code to `console.log(JSON.stringify(socket))` and I think you'll understand what's happening.

Comment: for `console.log(JSON.stringify(socket))` I get TypeError: cyclic object value. Is that what I am supposed to see?

Comment: Hmm. OK. so its not stringifiable. You were supposed to see that the socket object was not yet connected when that `console.log()` was called. But the reason you can see a connected socket object is that the console displays a live reference of that object so what you're seeing is actually a future version of `socket`

Comment: To prove this to yourself print `socket.id` in a `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @slebetman thanks! I've been searching SO for a while to find the answer to this. The best answer turns out to be a comment.

Comment: Add onconnect event handler of socket, and then try to use it. As @Oleg said, you accessed to early.

Comment: It's really weird. If I put `console.log(socket);
  console.log(socket.id);` side by side. the first one display the id in the object but the second one is `undefined`.  If it is delayed how come the first console log gets the id but the second one doesn't get the id? I think @slebetman 's answer may be the answer.

Comment: @newguy: If you're console.logging in a browser then this is a common question. In most browsers, if you console.log an object the browser will not print that object. Instead it will give you a GUI access to the object (in programmer's language let's say it gives you a reference to the object) so when you click to open you're not seeing the value of the object when you console.log but when you click on the object with your mouse which may be several seconds or even minutes after you console.log

Answer (score 16):

Socket.io needs some time for establish the connection. The best way I found to get ID on client-side is:

```
socket.on('connect', () => {console.log(socket.id)});
```

'connect' is system event which emitting when connection is ready.

(my current socket.io version is 1.7.2)

Answer (score 2):

set the port Lister and get the id via anonymous function 'http://localhost:8000'

```
this.socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
    this.socket.on('connect' , () => {
      console.log(this.socket.id);
    });
```