# Sockets do not clean up after disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a particular problem I am trying to fix. On the server, I have the following code...

```
// Establish a connection with a WebSocket.
io.on("connection", socket => {

  setTimeout(sendHeartbeat, 25000);

  function sendHeartbeat(){
    setTimeout(sendHeartbeat, 25000);
    io.sockets.emit("ping", socket.id);
    console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
  }

});
```

What is happening is that I am pinging the client every 25 seconds to all existing sockets, and I am sending the socket ID of the client that is connected.

On the client side I am just listening for the result and printing it to the console...

```
socket.on('ping',function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I start my server and a connection is made, on the server I have the following...

```
{ QofufgzXeTqGJcLOAAAA: Room { sockets: { QofufgzXeTqGJcLOAAAA: true }, length: 1 } }
```

This is correct as there is only 1 connection, however on the client side, every 25 seconds, the console looks as follows...

```
undefined
QofufgzXeTqGJcLOAAAA
```

Not sure where the `undefined` is coming from.

I continue to let the server run, eventually the socket disconnects and then reconnects (this happens every now and then), in this case the old socket should be removed and replaced with the new one, and this is precisely what happens on the server...

```
{ o2UFD7iHNxc94bPHAAAB: Room { sockets: { o2UFD7iHNxc94bPHAAAB: true }, length: 1 } }
```

But on the client side, the following gets printed every 25 seconds...

```
undefined
QofufgzXeTqGJcLOAAAA
o2UFD7iHNxc94bPHAAAB
```

I am trying to understand why the old sockets do not get removed. On every disconnect, an extra socket seems to be added. How can I fix this? In the examples above, only one single socket ID should be printed to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to use `setInterval` with `clearInterval`. The reason I am getting multiple sockets printed to the console is because the recursive function is never cleared, and so all instances run together asynchronously.

My new solution is the following...

```
// Ping the client to prevent disconnect.
let keepAlive = setInterval(sendHeartbeat, 25000);
function sendHeartbeat(){
    io.sockets.emit("ping", socket.id);
    console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
}
```

...and on disconnect I do...

```
socket.on("disconnect", async () => {
  clearInterval(keepAlive);
});
```

This solved my problem and now I only get 1 socket printed to the console, as expected. I still get the `undefined` one as well, but to solve that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089364/why-is-socket-id-undefined-in-the-browser) explains how to fix the issue.

Essentially, it takes a while for *socket.io* to establish a connection so `socket.on('connection', ...)` can be used to check if a connection is established. This will remove the `undefined` from the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change this to `io.once("connection")` which will mean that each time you connect, it does not add an additional binding, or you can subscribe to the disconnect event, and unbind from this event when the connection is disrupted. I tend to favour the second approach as it leads to cleaner code and fewer wtf moments later on

Comment: I have a disconnect even, I tried adding `socket.leave()` but that didn't work, do you have an example as to how I might be able to unbind from the even?